# Angular UI calendar rendering issue

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I have an issue with the rendering of the angular UI calendar. My app has several views that we use to navigate in between using routes. The main page has the angular calendar and when we load the main page the calendar loads fine. But when we navigate away from this page and comes back, the calendar failed to load and only the header part gets loaded with the title and the buttons. If a button (eg- month) is clicked then the whole calendar loads up again.

Is this something to do with rendering? any output is highly appreciated.

```
 [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/fECuY/4/ "jsfiddle"
```

Comment: im assuming you are using templates to load into this main page? so essentially the requests are async does the calendar provide an init method?

Comment: yes am using templates.. no init method defined in the calendar controller..only uiConfig and eventSources methods are defined.(as indicated by my jdfiddle)

Comment: the reason i asked about the init is because when leave the main page and then return to the main page since there is no full refresh the calendar will not load due to the js scripts related to calendar are already on the page. However when an action such a button click occurs to change calendar ui it will render the calendar because it already has the necessary actions tied to that button...

Comment: yes the calendar has a render method. http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/render/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by using resizing the window where the calendar got rendered within a timeout function.

Still I want to know how this render method can be used to re- render this calendar again. (in angular context)

arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/render example is catered for jquery..

Comment: Could you explain how you resized the window?

Comment: can use $window.innerWidth;